# finding a hosting company with unixODBC and FreeTDS support

Tags: php, sql-server, database, linux

I need to find a hosting company that provides a LAMP stack, the P being PHP.
Finding that is pretty easy, but I have a further requirement of unixODBC and FreeTDS or some equilant.

The project will require a remote connection to a Microsoft SQL 2005 database.

Most of the project will use a local MySQL database but it also requires data from a remote MS SQL 2005 database.

In my reading it looks like I'll need unixODBC and FreeTDS installed on the server to make that connection. So far I've been unable to find a shared host that provides these.

Can anyone suggest or use a host that might work? The project has budget limits so we we're hoping to find a shared host.

Comment: @patrick - welcome to stackoverflow. The site is dedicated to programming questions and your question is off topic. It will probably get migrated to SuperUser.com, which is a better forum for general computing questions.

Comment: Easiest solution would be to copy the data to the mysql database and just use that (maybe a cron that updates the data every day)

Comment: sorry about the off topic question. I will look for it on SuperUser.com.

Answer (score 1):

I would say near 0 chance. The requirements are pretty unusual, so mass hosting will not fullfill them. Try going for a well priced virtual server... that gives you the option to install yourself. or go windows hosting (WAMP) - shoult not make a difference and the price may be better than the virtual hosting (plus overhead of self administration) and obviously you have Odbc there if you insist on it (better use oledb).

Comment: I was able to find a host that has unixODBC and freetds configured and installed with PHP in a shared host. 

The company is Modwest hosting.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a host that has unixODBC and freetds configured and installed with PHP in a shared host. The company is Modwest hosting.